# Use XMLStarlet to add 2 similar XML subnodes and values

Tags: xml, bash, xmlstarlet

I want to use xmlstarlet within a Bash task in Azure DevOps to edit the below XML.

**Input:** `default.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ProxyEndpoint name="default">
    <PostFlow name="PostFlow">
        <Request/>
        <Response/>
    </PostFlow>
</ProxyEndpoint>
```

I want to make this code to the below.

**Expected output:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ProxyEndpoint name="default">
    <PostFlow name="PostFlow">
        <Request>
            <Step>
                <Name>FC-SpikeArrest</Name>
            </Step>
            <Step>
                <Name>FC-JWT</Name>
            </Step>
        </Request>
        <Response/>
    </PostFlow>
</ProxyEndpoint>
```

I used the below XML command and I can add one set of `Step` and `Name` tags with `FC-SpikeArrest`, but unable to add the `FC-JWT` tags.

```
xmlstarlet edit --omit-decl \
-s '/ProxyEndpoint/PostFlow/Request'      -t elem -n "Step" \
-s '/ProxyEndpoint/PostFlow/Request/Step' -t elem -n "Name" -v "FC-SpikeArrest" \
./default.xml >temp.xml
```

What is wrong here?

```
xmlstarlet edit --omit-decl \
-s '/ProxyEndpoint/PostFlow/Request'      -t elem -n "Step" \
-s '/ProxyEndpoint/PostFlow/Request/Step' -t elem -n "Name" -v "FC-SpikeArrest" \
./default.xml >temp.xml
mv temp.xml default1.xml

xmlstarlet edit --omit-decl \
-s '/ProxyEndpoint/PostFlow/Request'      -t elem -n "Step" \
-s '/ProxyEndpoint/PostFlow/Request/Step' -t elem -n "Name" -v "FC-JWT" \
./default1.xml >temp1.xml
mv temp1.xml default.xml
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in one command with the following:

```
xmlstarlet edit --omit-decl \
-s '/ProxyEndpoint/PostFlow/Request'         -t elem -n "Step" \
-s '/ProxyEndpoint/PostFlow/Request/Step'    -t elem -n "Name" -v "FC-SpikeArrest" \
-s '/ProxyEndpoint/PostFlow/Request'         -t elem -n "Step" \
-s '/ProxyEndpoint/PostFlow/Request/Step[2]' -t elem -n "Name" -v "FC-JWT" \
./default.xml > temp.xml
```

If you want to use two steps like you did, you'd still have to index the `Step` element with the `[2]`. Because otherwise the value element is added to *all* `Step` elements.

So the second command should look like this:

```
xmlstarlet edit --omit-decl \
-s '/ProxyEndpoint/PostFlow/Request'         -t elem -n "Step" \
-s '/ProxyEndpoint/PostFlow/Request/Step[2]' -t elem -n "Name" -v "FC-JWT" \
./default1.xml >temp1.xml
```

Comment: Thank you. The first command didn't work, not sure why. But when I split it up into two commands and used Step[2], it worked. Thanks again.